# It is always neccesary to use definition to show that a function is not differentiable at a given point?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose we are given $f(x)=x^{1/3}$. We know that Dom($f$) = $\mathbb{R}$ and $f'(x)=\frac{1}{3}x^{-2/3}$.

It is enough to conclude that $f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$ because $f'(x)=\frac{1}{3}x^{-2/3}$
is not defined at $0$ or it must be shown by definition that $f'(0)$ does not exist ?

More generally, if $f(x)$ is a function with domain $A$, and $g(x)$ is the derivate of $f(x)$ obtained by applying differentiation rules. If $g$ has domain $B \subset A$. It is enough to conclude that $f$ is not differentiable at any point $x\in A/B$ just because $g$ is not defined there or it must be shown by definition ?

Comment: It seems that you "know" that $f'(x)=\frac13x^{-2/3}$ when $x\ne0$. It seems you don't yet know anything about $f'(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, this must be shown by definition. For instance $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$ has derivative $2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x)$ for $x\neq 0$ but is still differentiable at $0$. There are a few general things that can be said, though; while derivatives can be discontinuous, as the previous example shows, they cannot have jump discontinuities. So if the formula giving the derivative on $B$ would lead to a jump discontinuity if extended to more of $A$, then you know the function is not differentiable at the missing points.